# Bugged Android Geocoder

Tags: android, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I recently faced some issues with the Android reverse Geocoder. Consider the following code:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(52.245210711511376, 20.988645628094673, 1);
if (addresses.size() == 0) return null;
return addresses.get(0);
```

If you type these lat/long in google maps, you get the address `Dzielna 9
Warszawa`. But if I take the `addresses.get(0)` result it returns an `Address` object with lat/long equals to `52.2302246`,`21.0000762` which is... not even close to the real location...
Have any of you faced the same issue? Is there something which can affect the Geocoder results?
My current solution is to use the [google web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#geocoding-request-and-response-latitudelongitude-lookup). But I would like to understand what causes this issue with the Geocoder and if there is anything to fix it.
Thank you.